# Was the Millennium Falcon a one-off or was it mass produced?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

Do the books ever specify whether or not another ship of this make exists? Or is it truly unique? Maybe a long time ago in a galaxy far far away manufacturers made single one-off units, but here that's kind of rare for something you'd assume to be pretty costly to build.

Comment: In the X-Wing and Tie Fighter computer games other ships of that model existed, but I don't know if the specific make and model was ever mentioned in any of the novelizations.

Comment: The Millennium Falcon is a modified cargo ship.

Comment: Add a legends tag if you want EU answers, otherwise your best bet is the Visual Dictionary.

Comment: I seriously doubt that *any* "commodity" spaceship could be built as a one-off. You might be able to build a speeder if you have the parts, or build some frickin' huge space station if you have the budget, but a hyperspace-capable freighter built as one-off would simply be too expensive.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The *Millennium Falcon* is not unique; it was a model YT-1300f Corellian light freighter. This implies that there are other similar ships, including other variations on the YT-1300 model.

You can find a lot of information about the *Millennium Falcon* in a companion book, [*Star Wars: The Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1465438157). The model number also appears on-screen at least once: in *Star Wars: Rebels* episode "Fighter Flight" on a poster.

Note, however, that the *Millennium Falcon* has been highly customized; some of the custom work is mentioned in *The Force Awakens*. It's not clear just how much of the ship is stock and how much is custom.

---

If you're willing to go outside Canon into Legends, the model number of the ship, and other similar Corellian light freighters, can be seen in some of the video games, and there is an entire novel called [*Millennium Falcon*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345507002) that details its history. The ship was serial #YT-1300 492727ZED, one of many such vessels, but from the beginning the ship was shown to have some "quirks" to distinguish it from its counterparts.

In Legends, the ship was also destroyed and rebuilt from scratch at least once, so [it's arguable as to whether it's still the same ship or not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).

Comment: By the time of TFA, my guess is that the Falcon would be lucky if any tiny part of it was factory original.

Comment: According to [SW Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/YT-1300_light_freighter) the "YT-1300" model number was mentioned in Star Wars Rebels cartoon (which is considered canon) on a poster.

Comment: Also, in the Force Awakens novel: *"Reports from our troopers on the ground indicate that the droid escaped capture by taking flight upon a stolen Corellian freighter, a YT model."*

Comment: A small technicality on implying that there are “similar YT1300a–e models”—that’s not _necessarily_ true. The _f_ could be for ‘freight(er)’, in which case there may have been a YT1300c (cargo) or a YT1300p (passenger), but not necessarily an alphabetical a–e series.

Comment: Agreed. Case in point: You've TIE/LN and TIE/IN but that doesn't imply AN-KN exists

Comment: It's his/hers/its.

Comment: Time for a [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) reference:)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier, I have done much think on this issue in regards to automobiles, and I have determined that the soul of the car (the piece that gives it its essence) is the windshield washer fluid reservoir.  I'm not sure if the Falcon had one of these, but it might have :)

Comment: The Millenium Falcon is like a Series Land Rover. Hundreds of thousands built, but one still in use today has very few original parts and unless the owner is a real pureist probably quite a few upgrades from original spec.

Comment: In the Thrawn trilogy the empire finds another yt1300 lookalike to try and kidnap Leia.

Comment: "Dammit Luke, I'm a smuggler, not a hyperspace topology engineer" "I thought you had modded this ship?" "Errr... yeah!" (long pause) "Ok, I was it a sales tactic, ok? OK?" (Luke makes some annoyed teenager gesture popular in the 70s)

Answer (score 94):

As has been mentioned, the *Millennium Falcon* is a highly modified YT-1300f freighter.

If you look carefully in *Attack of the Clones* and *Revenge of the Sith*, you can see other ships of the same class:

[image: YT-1300f freighters (Millennium Falcon type) in Star Wars prequels: above a shot from "Attack of the Clones" showing a landing field with 3 YT-1300s circled on the left; below a shot from "Revenge of the Sith" showing a YT-1300, circled, approaching a landing platform]

<sub>Image source: [10 Hidden Details in Star Wars Movies](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-easter-eggs-hidden-cameos-secrets/), *Screen Rant*</sub>

Comment: Worth noting that in the lower image, we're looking at the actual Millennium Falcon.

Comment: That's pretty neat. The top one especially because it suggests one of the mods was the cockpit sticking out the side.

Comment: @WadCheber - thanks, forgot that bit... but still, three YT-1300s in the AotC scene there

Comment: @KaiQing - they could be an earlier model...

Comment: @WadCheber That is also claimed in the image source, but how is that determined?

Comment: @Zommuter: Compare with the upper image. Cockpit off to the right, satelite dish on top. Neither of the YT-1300 in the upper image has those.

Comment: @DevSolar That's a good indicator, but is there an official statement on this?

Comment: @Zommuter: I bowed out of this "official" thing *long* ago. For me personally, what I read in my WestEndGames Star Wars 2nd ed. RPG book will *remain* "canon" forever, and the prequels never happened. I'm happier that way. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Good idea - then again this means you might not like Doctor Who :P

Comment: @Zommuter: That's why, despite YouTube snippets looking tempting, I never sat down to actually watch it. Sometimes, *dreaming* about things is much better than actually finding out. (Medichlorians, my backside...) ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar In case you ever do, start with the 2005 series (the one with Christopher Eccleston), at least _I_ still can't appreciate the old series...

Comment: @Zommuter - I believe Lucas commented on it.

Comment: @DevSolar [This other answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117165/15742) indicates that the cockpit and other items were standard options, not Han's personal tinkerings.

Comment: @DevSolar going with the WEG reference, their was a comment in the Source Book about the YT-1300 series. "You could take a thousand YT-1300s and in a year you would have a thousand different ships". So at least that addresses that there is a large porduction of the model.

Comment: @DevSolar - ha haa! I feel largely the same way. What was before A New Hope? Nothing. I haven't even decided if I accept force awakens until I know for sure why harrison ford is in the credits for ep 8

Comment: I see at least 3 "Puddle Jumpers" from SG:Atlantis in that painting...

Comment: not quite - i think the "puddle jumpers" you see are more square than the SG:A ones

Answer (score 56):

There is an official [*Millennium Falcon Haynes Manual*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Millennium-Falcon-Manual-Corellian-Freighter/dp/0857330969). The first part of the book discusses all the models of the YT-1300 Corellian Freighter which are available for purchase and later on it goes into specifics about the actual *Millennium Falcon* and its modifications.

In the 4th picture on Amazon (shown below) you can see the level of detail which has been made for the book. It shows some of the many configurations in which you can get your very own freighter.

[image: Modified YT-1300 Corellian Freighter options; the left side of the picture has descriptive text and a schematic showing how the different options fit in place on the basic hull shape; the right hand side shows 9 different possible configurations, including the cockpit on either side or in the middle and different drive options.]

Answer (score 23):

Think of the *Millennium Falcon* like this:

[image: Silver Nissan Skyline with blue detailing and logos, prop as used in the movie "2 Fast 2 Furious" on display at a show]

There are lots of Nissan Skylines, but this is a highly modified one (within the "universe" of the *Fast and the Furious* films, as well as in the real world) and is therefore unique. There is only one *Millennium Falcon*. Only one. But it is a modified version of a pretty common freighter. Indeed, in the old Legends game *Star Wars: Rebel Assault II: The Hidden Empire*, you have "The Corellia Star":

[image: Screenshot from a game showing a YT-1300 freighter in a hanger with a stormtrooper guard]

Comment: I like your analogy, but I think, more accurately, it's like http://imgur.com/ToF08jW

Comment: @corsiKa +1, but I think even more accurately, but at the expense of being less of an analogy, it is like https://i.stack.imgur.com/N01aT.jpg

Comment: lol. yeah i figured something like that. Some people like the virgin mobile guy build one off designs, so you never know. But I'd say even if there's only one millennium falcon by name, it's not any more unique than any base vehicle that's been modified. Someone made a bunch of them. Someone else converted one of them into a super ship then gave it a name. works for me

Comment: @corsiKa though you should see what's under the hood ;)

Answer (score 15):

To give a fully movie-canon answer, in *The Force Awakens*:

After Han informs Rey that they are on the *Millennium Falcon* we have the following lines:

> REY: This is the Millennium Falcon? You're Han Solo?
>
> [...]
>
> REY: This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs...!

Since Rey is an expert on salvage and ship models, and since she knows about the Kessel Run, we can reasonably infer that:

1. She knows what a YT-1300 Corellian freighter looks like.
2. She knows the *Millennium Falcon* was a YT-1300.

Yet she didn't suspect that the ship in the junkyard was the *Millennium Falcon*.   Therefore, it must be that **the *Millennium Falcon* is not unique**.

Comment: true true... that makes sense. Maybe she knows YT-1300 is an ancient model, like Al Bundy's Dodge in Married with Children. But hadn't considered this particular one was the famous falcon. Fine logic

Comment: 14 was the incorrect figure, so Han promptly corrected her.

Comment: @musicwithoutpaper:   Yes, and...

Comment: Sorry, but it is a fallacy to draw those two inferences from that line. If would be far more reasonable to infer that she had no clue what the Millennium Falcon looked like, much less that it was a YT-1300, or that she knew the ship she was in was a YT-1300. Most people will recognize a school bus as a bus, but couldn't tell you what make/model it might be. Or someone could have heard of the [Thrust2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust2) setting the land speed record in 1983, but it doesn't mean they have any idea how it looks or could pick it out if it were at a car show or junk yard.

Comment: Is this a real quote what she is saying? Isn't parsec (rather `((km/s)/Mpc)`) an unit that expresses a distance? So since the Kessel run is a route, does this mean it is of distance of 14 parsecs? But whats the relation to the Spaceship in this case then? .... I'm confused.

Comment: @Zaibis:   Um.... have you really never been exposed to the debate over *parsec* before??!   [See](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20359/kessel-run-in-12-parsecs-screenplay-error-or-part-of-the-movie)

Comment: @YLearn:  This is not a theory of logic class.   It's not about whether you can formally infer that.   I said you can *reasonably infer* that.   The clear impression, based on her expression and attitude and since Rey appears to be highly knowledgeable about ships and the Millenium Falcon breaking (apparently still holding) the Kessel Run record is that she most likely knows (1) and (2).   Calling it a fallacy and then (baselessly) claiming it is "far more likely" to infer something else is the fallacy. ... (cont)

Comment: Rey is an expert.  Don't you think an enthusiast would know what Thrust2 looks like, but not be able to identify it vs. another similar vehicle.   If an enthusiast happened upon that vehicle in an abandoned warehouse and then someone told said person it was Thrust2, don't you think they would say:  "This is Thrust2!   This is the car that beat the land speed record of 650 kilograms per lumen!"

Answer (score 9):

In Star Wars, Han says 3 things that hint at its modifications:

1. It has better-than-expected sublight and lightspeed engines than one would expect out of that kind of freighter.  ("She's got it where it counts, kid.")
2. It has a lightspeed engine that can shorten distances next to gravity wells ("It made the Kessel run in under 12 parsecs").  In the novels, this is taken to mean that a better lightspeed engine can go closer to stars and take shorter paths than would be possible with a lesser engine.  Very useful for getting away from Imperial Star Destroyers.
3. It has hidden cargo bays that apparently are VERY good at fooling scanners.  ("I use them for smuggling. I never thought I'd be smuggling myself in 'em.")

It's not clear if he won it that way or modified it himself.  But all this implies that it's a standard cargo ship that has been specially modified for smuggling.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F! This doesn't answer the question directly and seems more like a comment on someone else's post.  However, this could be expanded to maybe answer the question.  As it stands, your answer might be flagged for removal.

Comment: While we are at the topic: Is it ever explained why the Millenium Falcon is such a great combat ship? It’s a light freighter but still easily dealing with Tie-Fighters.

Comment: To be fair, the scanners hadn't actually been used yet when Han proclaimed "I use [the hidden cargo bays] for smuggling," so we don't really know if they fool the scanners or not.

Comment: Don't forget "I've made a lot of special modifications myself."

Answer (score 3):

I hope I am doing this correctly, to point to an existing question-and-answer.  Not *literally* a duplicate, but in effect the substance has been covered.

The sense of this question was addressed in the discussion of another that was answered at ['What is the Millennium Falcon’s hull and structure made of?'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112503/what-is-the-millennium-falcon-s-hull-and-structure-made-of/112555).  It involves the Haynes Manual, as has been mentioned here.

The essence is that the *Falcon* is no more a one-off in production terms than any other YT-1300, in the sense that multiple design options were so flexible to start with that the term doesn't really apply.  All of the YT-1300s were sort-of one-offs, therefore, but this particular one seems to have become even-more-unique (tm) over time since manufacture.

Comment: That is a fine question indeed, but I wouldn't say you could derive a duplicate from it even if the substance is covered somewhere in there. I posted this question because I couldn't find it in basic searches on this site. Felt it should be covered.

Comment: Fine, as far as I'm concerned.  I'm not competing, just drawing attention to something that made this seem suddenly rather familiar.  I hope that my earlier efforts might help.

Comment: @CaptainCranium: just because an answer to another question mentions, in passing, a tidbit that could -- if you squint and tilt your head just right -- be taken as an answer to this question does ***NOT*** mean that the questions are duplicates. Two questions are duplicates if and only if they're asking the same thing; answers can't change this.

Comment: @Martha You seem not completely to have read or understood what I wrote: I carefully made sure of _not_ proclaiming a duplicate.  That was the point of indicating a lot of nearby information that was relevant, without criticising OP for not having read the entire world before asking. Still, thanks for the joke about 'in passing, a tidbit', when the entire detailed answer to a _different_ question bears helpfully on this one.

Answer (score 1):

In [*Heir to the Empire*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heir_to_the_Empire) (part of the Empire trilogy by Timothy Zahn) the Nogrhi commandos use a YT-1300 to try to trick Han and Leia so they can kidnap them. Han expresses **genuine surprise that they've been able to find the same make and model.**

> *“Good question,” Han said grimly. He leaned out again, taking a hard
> look this time … and when he ducked back under cover there was a
> sardonic half-grin on his face. “Simple answer: that’s not the
> Falcon.”*
>
> *“What?” Wedge asked, his jaw dropping a couple of centimeters.*
>
> *“It’s a fake,” Han told him. “**I can’t believe it-these guys actually
> dug up another working YT-1300 freighter somewhere.***”
>
> *Wedge whistled softly. “Boy, they must really want you bad.”*

In the [*Star Wars: The Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Vehicles_and_Vessels) factbook (published in 1996) the section on the *Millennium Falcon* says that

> *the Falcon appeared to be no different from the **thousands of other Corellian Engineering YT-1300 light freighters** plying the star routes of the Empire.*

So from that it would appear that it's a mass-produced vehicle.

---

Also, the *[Outrider](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Outrider)* piloted by Dash Rendar (in various EU Novels and games) appears to be a later model in the YT series of ships as this is listed as a YT-2400 light freighter.

Comment: Is that a canon book? Also does this suggest it was mass produced or a one/two-off?

Comment: This would benefit from some capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: @Edlothiad - It's an EU novel, hence never canon.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of dropping in the quotes you've mentioned as well as referencing (and linking) the books to Wookieepedia.