# What is the purpose of the Millennium Falcon's "mandibles"?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117165/3823) points out this page

[image]

from [Millennium Falcon Haynes Manual](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Millennium-Falcon-Manual-Corellian-Freighter/dp/0857330969) which refers to the two projections on the bows of all YT-1300 Correlian Freighters as ***mandibles***.

## What is their purpose or function?

Comment: Chicks dig mandibles.

Comment: I feel like I read somewhere about cargo lifting with them. Either I'm just imagining it or if I really read that it was most likely in the Han Solo Adventures trilogy - hardly canon.

Comment: Surely the Solo movie answers this and makes possibly both answers below incorrect, from a canon perspective?

Comment: @Darren, what's the proposed canon answer?

Comment: @ThePopMachine they hold an escape pod - https://goo.gl/images/Ee7jHh

Comment: @Darren... So write an answer!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the book "Incredible Cross-Sections of Star Wars: The Ultimate Guide to Star Wars Vehicles and Spacecraft", the mandibles hold various sensors and an anti-concussion field generator. Three is also the freight barge clamp so the YT-1300 can act like a barge or tugboat and push around large cargo. Also on the port mandible there is the shield generator and projector. On the inner side of the mandibles there is a freight loading arm. Click on the image to see a larger version.

[image: DK cross section]

Another purpose is for moving freight around, where the mandibles attach to cargo and push them around, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: I think the **freight loading arm** makes sense as the key thing that justifies the shape and presence of the mandibles.

Comment: and the "electromagnetic freight barge clamp" position http://i.stack.imgur.com/EA69H.jpg

Comment: That second image actually makes sense.... especially since the Falcon is supposed to be a freighter, but the cutaway shows there's almost no room for freight.

Comment: And it even explains why the cockpit is way over on the side.

Comment: Where do yo actually sleep in this vessel?!

Comment: @flq in the crew quarters near the engine

Answer (score 0):

The Falcon, like other ships in its class can be used as a cargo pusher. The (canon) [Star Wars: Rebel Files](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rebel_Files) has an image of a newer YT-model freighter moving what appears to be a smaller ship.

[image]