# How big exactly is the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

The Millennium Falcon is a pretty big ship. But what are its exact dimensions and mass?

Comment: Mass is proving quite hard to pin down.

Comment: Hmm. The canonical mass of an X-Wing is 10 tons. If we assume that the Falcon contains about the same material as twenty of those, then that gives us a baseline weight of approx. 200 tons.

Comment: @Valorum You typically have to weld it on, otherwise it'll fall off again.

Comment: Based on Valorum's 1st reference, volume is ~~~~= 30 x 30 x 7 metres or about 6300 cubic metres.  Make that say 5000 m^3 due to no box like shape. Satellite launchers tend to have densities of about 1000 kg/m^3 (same as water). The MF is not fuel-mass intensive but also does not depend on having an ultra low density. A means SG of 0.1 to 0.2 puts the mass maybe in the range  500 - 1000 tons.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It seems there aren't any large fuel tanks either, and let's not forget this is a cargo ship - though according to ICS, the cargo space volume seems a pretty small fraction of the entire ship (more like a caravan than a real cargo hauler). Still, a lot of empty space - lots of big rooms and corridors.

Comment: @Luaan Yes - I allowed 10-20% of the mass of an orbital launcher. The Hyperdrive engine  is a substantial mass, of course.

Comment: I think its mass is about 2 parsecs

Comment: @Luaan its not really a cargo freighter - its a cargo pusher.  That's why the YT-1300 has that weird "fork" shape on the front and the cockpit is offset, to see around the cargo.  The internal compartments are purely for smuggling.   See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117365/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-millennium-falcons-mandibles/

Comment: @Criggie That would explain the oversized engines, at least. But there's still freight loading cranes, freight loading doors, freight elevators... clearly it's _meant_ to carry cargo on the inside too, but... where? :D Maybe Solo just has a particularly trimmed down version to maximize speed (or just pimped out for extra comfort). There are two areas marked out as cargo holds, but they don't really seem designed for cargo - maybe they're also supposed to be under the floor (like the secret compartments), or again, Han repurposed them.

Comment: @Luann - The deck plans of an [unaltered YT freighter](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/3/35/Yt1300f-OM.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20190321142947) show plenty of space for cargo. Han, on the other hand, is mainly smuggling drugs which don't need lots of space.

Answer (score 26):

Various sources about the dimension of the Millennium Falcon exist. They're not all in agreement, but most of the modern canon sources state that the ship's length is around 35-40m and that its height is around 7.5m, not including its landing struts.

### Canon

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Solo: A Star Wars Story - The Official Guide](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story_The_Official_Guide)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Incredible Cross-Sections](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Incredible_Cross-Sections)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sup><sub>[The Force Awakens: Incredible Cross Sections](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections)</sub></sup>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Complete Vehicles - Incredible Cross-Sections (2020)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Complete_Vehicles,_New_Edition)</sup></sub>

### Legends

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Millennium Falcon Owner's Workshop Manual](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon_Owner%27s_Workshop_Manual)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Build the Millennium Falcon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Build_the_Millennium_Falcon_(De_Agostini))</sup></sub>

The DeAgostini factbooks seem to have persistent error, identifying the ship as 26.7 metres long.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Official Starships & Vehicles Collection #1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Official_Starships_%26_Vehicles_Collection)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Official Fact Files #4](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[The New Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Vehicles_and_Vessels)</sup></sub>

Corrected in the rebooted magazine series from 2013 onward.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Official Fact Files (2013) #1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_(2013))</sup></sub>

Comment: I love how in that first image that the Falcon has dimensions of a whole number of feet and inches, but speed is a nice round number of kph.  Talk about mixing up units, let alone from a far away galaxy a long time ago.

Comment: @PeterM If you do the conversions, you get: 7.58m is 24ft 10.4in and 40.80m is 133ft 10.3in. The other way, you get 7.59m and 40.82m. Either the metric values were used as a base (rounded up to the next inch), or the conversions are plainly wrong. It's just that 7.58 doesn't look nice and round.

Comment: "Cargo : 100 MT." - Isn't that supposed to mean there's 10,000 cubic feet of cargo space? https://www.quora.com/How-big-is-a-100-ton-ship

Comment: On a different note, it occurs to me that the first source greatly differs on the length likely because the Falcon in *Solo* includes the escape pod.

Comment: @Mazura - It can carry 100 metric tons. That might be 4 cubic metres of gold, 12 cubic metres of steel or100 cubic metres of water

Comment: Probably extrapolated by seeing those shots of Luke in the gunner's seat (one of the best examples showing a human inside a part recognizable from the outside), and comparing it to Mark Hammill's actual height.

Comment: @DarrellHoffman - There are multiple remarks in the 'making of Star Wars' books about how the setmakers struggled to make the exterior of the Falcon look like it could possibly contain the internal sets that we see, with the cast walking around with ample headroom

Comment: Some extended discussion about units of measurement etc. has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133499/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-how-big-exactly-is-the-millennium-falcon); please feel free to continue there.

Comment: Also, considering that Solo ejected the entire front portion (escape pod) and turned Lando Calrissian's shining, sleek beauty into the galaxy's fastest piece of junk (I can't imagine how many times it's been scratched by Imperial fighers), I wouldn't be surprised if there is some variance between different figures.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon):

> Length. 34.37 meters.
> Width. 25.61 meters.
> Height/depth. 8.27 meters (including lower cannon and upper sensor array)
> MGLT. 75 MGLT.
> Maximum speed (atmosphere) 1,050 km/h.
> Engine unit(s) 2 Girodyne SRB42 sublight engines (heavily modified)

Comment: The note says that figure is taken from, _Solo: A Star Wars Story The Official Guide_.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - The only place I've seen it referred to as 34.37m is the 'Build the Millennium Falcon' book.

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, my comment came after your answer which categorically demonstrates that the values cited in Wookieepedia don't match the values in the source they are citing. Unless there are significantly different values in different editions.

Comment: Per my answer, the whole thing is a big jumbly mess.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but I thought it was worth mentioning as potentially helpful supplemental info.

Supposedly, [the Millennium Falcon at Disney World](https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/destinations/hollywood-studios/star-wars-galaxys-edge/) is constructed at full scale. A little googling finds [this reference](https://attractionsmagazine.com/photo-update-millennium-falcon-has-landed-in-disneyland/), which is being a bit wonky at the time I'm posting this. But I did have the privilege of visiting the park myself, and I'm positive I also read this fact someplace while I was there.

Maybe someone can find a better source with more data on the Disney MF?

That said, as to whether the Disney Millennium Falcon is truly what we'd think of as "full scale" (i.e., what we see on screen), I have no way of knowing. Seeing it up close, my initial reaction was that I thought it'd be *slightly* larger (for instance, it struck me how crammed the cockpit seemed like it would be). But either way, that thing is pretty close to what you'd imagine.

If anyone has some fancy imaging software that's good with measuring distances (or knows a Disney employee who can go measure it), it might make a good point of comparison.

**Edit:** Following @Valorum's comment below, I completely agree that what we see on-screen *inside* the ship is vastly incongruent with what we see *outside*. I only mention the cockpit as an exception to this because that's the one interior section we typically can see from external views.

In any case, it might be interesting (or at least fun) to know how the dimensions of the Disney Falcon match up with the figures quoted in other responses here.

Comment: The 'full scale' ship in the film was wildly inconsistent externally to what we see inside.

Comment: @Valorum You're right, of course. There's no way the interior sets would fit inside the real-life model at Disney. The "canonical outside" has to be different than the "canonical inside," I guess.

Comment: Timelord science allows this sort of thing.

Comment: Well if the Millenium Falcon is a TARDIS it would be perfect for smuggling.